# React-like conditional rendering in Flutter

Tags: reactjs, flutter, for-loop, foreach

One of the most widely-used patterns in React is conditional rendering like this:

```
{ condition && array.map(item, index) => return (...) }
```

Moving to Flutter, I'm trying to do the same but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
children: <Widget>[
   organizations.length > 0 ?
      for (var item in array) {
        new Card(...)
      }
   : Text('Nope. No items here.')
]
```

Another pattern I tried:

```
children: <Widget>[

   if(array.length > 0)
      for (var org in organizations)
         new Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: ListTile(
               leading: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0),
               title: Text(org['name'] ?? ''),
               subtitle: Text(org['description'] ?? ''),
               trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            ),
         ),

    else
       Text('Nope. No items here.')
       Text('What if else is multi-line?')
]

// Errors:
// Expected to find ']'
// Expected identifier
```

Oddly enouogh, the codes do not work.

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for creating a list of items and filtering items is slightly different between JS and Dart

You could write:

```dart
children: <Widget>[
  if (organizations.length > 0)
    for (var item in array)
      Card(...)
  else 
    Text('Nope. No items here.'),
]
```

Comment: I'm sure your recommendation is correct but I wonder why it's not working? Please see my edits. Thank you.

Comment: Don't put a `,` after Card

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I would use the layout widget (`Column` / `Row`) at collection level, so for example:

```dart
Container(
  child: organizations.length > 0 ? 
    Column(
      children: organizations.map((item)=>Card(...)),
    ) 
    : Text('Nope. No items here.'),
)
```